# Point a domain registered via GoDaddy to a hosting package from Strato

Tags: web-hosting, 301-redirect, domain-registration, godaddy

I have a hosting package that is hosted at Strato and a `.eu` domain that was registered via Strato as well. However, I want to use one of the new Top-Level-Domains for the website on my Strato-webspace. Unfortunately, the company that holds the rights to the TLD I want to use only accepts certain ICANN-certified registrars like GoDaddy.

So the problem is, I have a webspace hosted at Strato and want a domain that I can't register via Strato. So my plan is to register the new domain and redirect it using a `301` HTTP redirect, **so that visitors will still see the new domain in their browser**.

Is this approach advisable? Both performance and SEO-wise? If not, is there a better way? Also, which domain will show up in Google: the new gTLD domain or the `.eu` domain?

Comment: I am not sure what the problem is using GoDaddy?? They are one of the largest, most popular, and most reliable registrars in the world.

Comment: It's not a problem, rather a technical question about pointing a domain registered via GoDadddy to a webspace hosted at Strato, as well as the implications for the questions above

Comment: I am assuming that you have the .eu domain and you want something like a .com. Using that as an example, the .com has a larger penetration in the search engines than .eu. Personally, I would chose one over the other. If you think that .eu is more valuable then go for that. If you think the .com is more valuable then go for that. You can have both. You would just be redirecting one to the other. Does this sound like your scenario?? And if so, what would be your preference- .eu or .<whatever you actually have in mind>??

Comment: You don't have to assume if you read the question °v° I meant one of the new gTLD domains that become available at the moment, .world, to be exact. However, I am not sure if the 301 redirect is a good permanent solution, since even though the visitors would see the .world domain in their browsers, they would technically be forwarded to the .eu domain. So I'm asking if the 301 redirect is a feasible approach when I'm planning on using the .world domain permanently instead of the .eu domain. Also, (tbc)

Comment: Also, I wanted to know if using the 301 redirect will affect the  performance, and what it would mean for the google rating (will google show links to my site as .world or .eu? Or - worst case scenario - will they be considered two seperate sites and penalized for duplicate content?)

Comment: Ooopppsss. I get it now. I missed the word *new* and thought of one of the traditional TLDs. Gotcha! You will have to use a 301 redirect or be hit with penalties from the search engines for duplicate content. In this case, using the .eu TLD would be more valuable and redirecting the .world to .eu likely the best. After seeing how .world penetrates the search engines (Google mostly), then you can reverse it if necessary later if .world behaves something like .com that enjoys a large penetration. Am I being clear as mud?? ;-)

Comment: Yeah, kind of. But if I do this (redirect my .world domain to the .eu domain), would Google show pages on my site with the .eu or .world domain? Also, I'm pretty sure that I want to use .world, regardless of how it would affect my rating. Of course, this would impose a problem if googles showed links to my site as .eu and not as .world ...

Comment: Okay. .World it is! ;-) It really is a preference. Only one would rank with a 301 redirect. If you want both to have a presence in the search engines, then both sites would have to be unique enough from each other and rank on their own.

Comment: And the one ranked in search engines, would that be .world or the .eu domain in this scenario?

Comment: The one that would rank would be the one that the 301 redirect is targeted to. In this case, since you want .world, you would use a blanket 301 redirect from .eu to .world and the .world site will rank and the .eu site would almost drop out of search entirely. It you want both sites to rank, then each site has to be unique enough as not to be penalized as having duplicate pages.

Comment: Well then thats exactly the problem i was talking about in my question. I have my webspace hosted at Strato, but I can only get the domain via godaddy :( so is there another way to accomplish this?

Comment: This is what I am not understanding about your problem. Registering a domain name and hosting are two different things. You can register your domain name with GoDaddy and host it anywhere you want. Are you saying that your host will not allow this somehow?? That would be very unusual.

Comment: I'm asking **how** I can connect a domain registered via GoDaddy to a webspace hosted at Strato! :)

Comment: BTW- I see there are several Strato web hosting sites. Which one are you referring to?

Comment: The German one, strato.de

Comment: Oh!! You would simply create your site on your host using whatever control panel they provide. After that, then you would register your domain name via GoDaddy. When done, you would add an A record that points the domain name to an IP address your host gives you. Then, optionally, you can create a CNAME record that allowes www to be aliased to the domain name. After that, you are done except for the website. BTW- GoDaddy can really help you with this via chat, e-mail, or phone. Their support is fairly good.

Comment: Ok I searched the internet for some more information, using "external" domains with the Strato Webhosting packages isn't possible :/ Due to the shared IP system they're using, I can't get one explicit IP adress to which I could point my .world domain :(

Comment: You do not need an exclusive IP address under normal circumstances and should be able to point any domain to a shared server, unless of course there is some new thing exclusive to .world.

Comment: Yeah but I would need to point the domain to the Strato nameserver and tell the Strato NS that I want to use this domain for my webhosting package, which, as far as I can see, is not possible in the Strato account management (several threads in some forums I found also suggest that this is not possible with the Strato Webhosting packages, even though it's possible with most webspace providers)

Comment: I would suggest calling them to be sure. Do not listen to chatter on the net. Get it straight from the horses mouth. I suspect you may be surprised. Push comes to shove, you can also change hosts. I am hot sure who is good in Germany though so I cannot help you with that. I wish I could recommend someone.

Comment: Anytime!! I am here everyday if you need me. This may help if you need to change hosts: http://web-hosting-review.toptenreviews.com/

Answer (score 1):

All one needs to do is to create an `A` record in their DNS to point a registered domain to a web binding at a host.

`301` and `302` redirects would infer pointing the register's URI to a web hosting service then redirecting the traffic to an entirely new web hosting service.

To answer your question about SEO / speed, you're essentially doubling your First-Packet response time and including two DNS lookups by redirecting the first domain to the second one...not a good idea.

`301` and `302` redirects should only be used to redirect old URI traffic to a new source location on the same web host once the site is already established. An example would be if you moved a popular article from `example.com?popular=thing` to `example.com/popular/thing` so one does not lose the old traffic and backlinks from other sites.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of changing nameservers of domain lets say abc.com point the A record in your domain panel to your hosting provider and o redirection is required

Any redirect will definitely affect your seo ranking

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately, my hoster doesn't allow that. +1 for the alternative approach though!